# Module update manually multiple versions at once

Tags: views, 7, updating

Actually my website use module views 7.x-3.5 version. The last version is 7.x-3.11, so i need update. My question is if I can upgrade (replace folders and code) directly to version 7.x-3.11 and run mysite\update.php or I need apply each new version separately running update.php for each, e.g. views 7.x-3.6, views 7.x-3.7...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace it with the latest version and run **update.php**. Drupal modules keep track of what version data schema it's on; **update.php** will apply the needed DB updates since 7.x-3.5.